# How to discover the service packs applied to my SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm running SSMS 2008, and I can see the version numbers in Help -> About. But how do I know from these version numbers if the SP2 have been installed in my machine?

Here are my version numbers from SSMS:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.4000.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        10.50.4000.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)     3.85.1132
Microsoft MSXML                 2.6 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer             8.0.6001.18702
Microsoft .NET Framework                2.0.50727.3623
Operating System                    5.1.2600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually running SQL Server 2008 R2, and you have the SP2 installed, according to this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Answer (score 4):

See the SQL Server version number post here:

http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

It contains a list of all SQL Server versions and service packs and which four-part version number those refer to.

Your `10.50.4000.0` is SQL Server **2008 R2 with SP2**.

To get the version number of the database engine (not the management tool or the analysis services), use

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

This output will look something like this:

> Microsoft SQL Server **2012** - 11.0.2218.0 (X64)
>   Jun 12 2012 13:05:25
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: **Service Pack 1**)

would also include the service pack level that's applied to your system.